# Best way to combine data and graphics representations in Qt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm currently developing an application to generate simple pixel art for an embedded application. This application only cares about the color index of each "pixel" in a sprite/tile:

```
[0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B
 0,2,A,3,F,F,9,B]
```

Where each pixel in this image contains an index to a color palette in hex, so `0` would be the first color and `F` would be the 16th. The embedded application only consumes this array of color indexes, so the visual representation on screen is only useful to the artist while they're modifying this array on the backend.

I already have a simple editor working perfectly using `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`, with an 800x800 pixel scene where each 100x100 pixel square is an actual pixel (basically, an 8x8 sprite/tile scaled up by a factor of 100).

I know there's an axiom of data management where data should not be represented separately, but instead should be interconnected so that changing it in one representation is bound to the other - essentially, not manually managing updates for each representation independently.

So my question is, what would be the most Qt/Pythonic way of managing this relationship? I've considered connecting `QGraphicsScene/View` events to updating my data representation directly, and the visual representation is updated based on the contents of the data array afterwards. I've also considered subclassing `QGraphicsItem`. Suffice to say, there are many ways to skin this cat, however my limited experience with Qt is preventing me from determining which is the most sane.

Comment: There is no Qt or pythonic way for what you want.

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to answer without buidlng the application myself. However in terms of data management seems like a borg is what you are looking for: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch05s23.html. Combining this with signals/slots is very powerful.

Comment: Ok then, is there a knowledgeable bit of advice on a "best" way to do this? I also considered generating the array on "saving" to a file for consumption by the embedded application - but the best way I can think of doing this is testing the color at the center of each "pixel". This however seems terribly hacky. - @Spencer thanks I'll look into that!

Comment: @ConnorSpangler First of all, a simple question: if it's an 8x8 sprite, why are there only 7 rows? Besides that, let me better understand: do you want something that "automatically" reacts to any change that is applied to that array?

Comment: @musicamante Simply forgot how to count when making that representation haha, it's supposed to be 8 rows and 8 columns. I would say that since I am using events bound to QGraphicsView/Scene (e.g. mousePressEvent), I want something that does exactly what you're asking: updates the array as the primary data representation, and then updates the visual representation based on the updated state of the array. This way, I am not updating one independently of the other: their states are bound to each other. Yes, I could just update them independently, but this as I understand is very bad practice.

Comment: Create a data structure (a model) that is notified about the events of each item and then according to your business logic update the necessary items.

Comment: Using a data model to manage an interface to the data sounds reasonable. QAbstractItemModel already has all the signals/slots you'd probably need, makes sense to use it (and as a bonus you could visualize the data in a "standard" model view as well). For instance each sprite could be a top-level item with its pixel array as children. Then design/use the custom graphics view to show the data. I'm not clear if the index into which the pixel data points to is something static or also dynamic.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to use a "Qt model", just a class that is notified of the events, make your own logic and update the items

Comment: @MaximPaperno Interesting - the index into which the pixel data points is itself dynamic, as it's a 16-color palette which can be customized by the user. I would want any updates to it to result in an update in the graphical representation as well. So a change to the palette would not result in a change to the underlying data representation, since the index in the color palette has not changed, just the color it points to has.

Comment: The more I look at the model/view paradigm, the more it seems exactly suited to this use case. @eyllanesc I understand why you argue it's not necessary, and I think I'm going to go with your advice of a simple class to start. Later I think I'll investigate the model/view paradigm if only to get some familiarity with it as it seems very powerful and robust. Thanks for the advice everyone!

Comment: Ah, that does complicate it a bit potentially. If there's a hierarchy of palette to sprites then it may work to manage the data with one model, otherwise you may be looking at 2 data structs/models which are connected with signals/slots (one palette and another for the sprites).  And no the data doesn't _have to_ be a "Qt model" but I don't really see why not... it just provides a standard interface to the data.

Comment: Actually my advice is that my advice is to model-view, but it is not necessary to use the Qt models (QAbstractItemModel, QStandardItemModel, etc.) but a class that has the references of the items, and that class is managed by a controller that receives the events from the model and make decisions to update the model. A model is simply a structure that stores information that can be modified.

Comment: Agreed, the model (Q*ItemModel.. or otherwise) is the interface to the data, it doesn't even have to actually store the data. Like a database-based model for example where it's actually just a bunch of queries to a data store.

Comment: I agree with @eyllanesc: as we say, there's no need for a crane to kill a fly. Using a QAbstractItemModel for a 8x8 matrix seems like a massive overshooting. You could just create a QObject subclass (to get advantage of signals) that behaves like a list or, even better, a [8 rows based] list of [8 items] lists. Then you can also override `__getitem__` and/or `__setitem__` in such a way that it can use a two-int based "slice" for [row:column], almost as numpy does for bidimensional arrays, and emit custom signals accordingly.

Comment: Just implemented this basic model/view paradigm via signals & slots and it works absolutely perfectly. Thanks everyone for the advice!